# XAMPP phpmyadmin and MySQL databases not matching

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

So I have a total of 6 databases in the PHPMyAdmin page but when I run the MySQL client, it only shows 2 of them. Moreover, I am not able to create a database using the command client, it shows

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
>   'new'

I've checked the server versions on both and they are the same, can't figure out what the problem is though.

Comment: Sounds like a user/permission issue.

Comment: which os are using ?